# Python - Creating an array for a series within a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, series

I'd like to add values calculated in a for loop to a series so that it can be its own column in a dataframe. So far I've got this: the y values are from a dataframe named `block`.

```
N = 12250
for i in range(0,N-1):
    y1 = block.iloc[i]['y']
    y2 = block.iloc[i+1]['y']
    diffy[i] = y2-y1
```

I'd like to make `diffy` its own series instead of just replacing the `diffy` val on each loop

Comment: could you perhaps clarify your desired output?

Comment: so `s=pd.Series(range(0,N-1))` and `s.shift(-1)-s` ?

Comment: What kind of object is `diffy`? A list? A dictionary? A pandas.Series?

Answer (score 1):

Some sample data (assume N = 5):

```
N = 5

np.random.seed(42)
block = pd.DataFrame({
    'y': np.random.randint(0, 10, N)
})

   y
0  6
1  3
2  7
3  4
4  6
```

You can calculate `diffy` as follow:

```
diffy = block['y'].diff().shift(-1)[:-1]

0   -3.0
1    4.0
2   -3.0
3    2.0
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

`diffy` is a `pandas.Series`. If you want list, add `.to_list()`. If you want a numpy array, add `.values`